# Most frequently occurring numbers across multiple columns using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with numbers in multiple columns listed by date, what I'm trying to do is find out the most frequently occurring numbers across the whole data set, also grouped by date.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

def lotnorm(pdobject) :
    # clean up special characters in the column names and make the date column the index as a date type.
    pdobject["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(pdobject["Date"])
    pdobject = pdobject.set_index('Date')
    for column in pdobject:
        if '#' in column:
            pdobject = pdobject.rename(columns={column:column.replace('#','')})
    return pdobject

def lotimport() :
    lotret = {}
    # list files in data directory with csv filename
    for lotpath in [f for f in glob.glob("data/*.csv")]:
        lotname = lotpath.split('\\')[1].split('.')[0]
        lotret[lotname] = lotnorm(pd.read_csv(lotpath))
    return lotret
    


print(lotimport()['ozlotto'])
```

------------- Output ---------------------

```
             1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
Date                                          
2020-07-07   4   5   7   9  12  13  32  19  35
2020-06-30   1  17  26  28  38  39  44  14  41
2020-06-23   1   3   9  13  17  20  41  28  45
2020-06-16   1   2  13  21  22  27  38  24  33
2020-06-09   8  11  26  27  31  38  39   3  36
...         ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
2005-11-15   7  10  13  17  30  32  41  20  14
2005-11-08  12  18  22  28  33  43  45  23  13
2005-11-01   1   3  11  17  24  34  43  39   4
2005-10-25   7  16  23  29  36  39  42  19  43
2005-10-18   5   9  12  30  33  39  45   7  19
```

The output I am aiming for is

```
Number frequency
45     201
32     195
24     187
14     160
48     154
```

--------------- Updated with append experiment -----------

I tried using append to create a single series from the dataframe, which worked for individual lines of code but got a really odd result when I ran it inside a for loop.

```
temp = lotimport()['ozlotto']['1']
print(temp)
temp = temp.append(lotimport()['ozlotto']['2'], ignore_index=True, verify_integrity=True)
print(temp)
temp = temp.append(lotimport()['ozlotto']['3'], ignore_index=True, verify_integrity=True)
print(temp)

lotcomb = pd.DataFrame()
for i in (lotimport()['ozlotto'].columns.tolist()):
    print(f"{i} - {type(i)}")
    lotcomb = lotcomb.append(lotimport()['ozlotto'][i], ignore_index=True, verify_integrity=True)

print(lotcomb)
```

Comment: what is your expected out put  ?

Comment: a list of the n top occurring numbers with their frequency

Comment: Please show to us

Comment: I've updated the problem description

Answer (score 1):

This solution might be the one you are looking for.

```
freqvalues = np.unique(df.to_numpy(), return_counts=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=freqvalues[0], data=freqvalues[1], columns=["Frequency"])
df2.index.name = "Numbers"
df2
```

Output:

```
    Frequency
Numbers     
1   6
2   5
3   5
5   8
6   4
7   7
8   2
9   7
10  3
11  4
12  2
13  8
14  1
15  4
16  4
17  6
18  4
19  5
20  9
21  3
22  4
23  2
24  4
25  5
26  4
27  6
28  1
29  6
30  3
31  3
...     ...
70  6
71  6
72  5
73  5
74  2
75  8
76  5
77  3
78  3
79  2
80  3
81  4
82  6
83  9
84  5
85  4
86  1
87  3
88  4
89  3
90  4
91  4
92  3
93  5
94  1
95  4
96  6
97  6
98  1
99  6

97 rows × 1 columns
```

Comment: That will give the count for a single series, which is part of the solution, but it still doesn't actually merge the 7 columns into a single data set for evaluation.
Looking into it more closely, the append method, might work but I'm having some trouble with it working within a for loop. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.max(axis=0)
```

for columns

```
df.max(axis=1)
```

for index

Comment: That appears to just give the most the most frequent number in each column, as opposed to seeing the whole df as a single dataset and then giving the n-top of that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the final answer I came up with was a mix of a few things including some of the great input from people in this thread. Essentially I do the following:

Pull in the CSV file and clean up the dates and the column names, then convert it to a pandas dataframe.
Then create a new pandas series and append each column to it ignoring dates to prevent conflicts.

Once I have the series, I use Vioxini's suggestion to use numpy to get counts of unique values and then turn the values into the index, after that sort the column by count in descending order and return the top 10 values.

Below is the resulting code, I hope it helps someone else.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np

def lotnorm(pdobject) :
    # clean up special characters in the column names and make the date column the index as a date type.
    pdobject["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(pdobject["Date"])
    pdobject = pdobject.set_index('Date')
    for column in pdobject:
        if '#' in column:
            pdobject = pdobject.rename(columns={column:column.replace('#','')})
    return pdobject

def lotimport() :
    lotret = {}
    # list files in data directory with csv filename
    for lotpath in [f for f in glob.glob("data/*.csv")]:
        lotname = lotpath.split('\\')[1].split('.')[0]
        lotret[lotname] = lotnorm(pd.read_csv(lotpath))
    return lotret
    

lotcomb = pd.Series([],dtype=object)
for i in (lotimport()['ozlotto'].columns.tolist()):
    lotcomb = lotcomb.append(lotimport()['ozlotto'][i], ignore_index=True, verify_integrity=True)


freqvalues = np.unique(lotcomb.to_numpy(), return_counts=True)
lotop = pd.DataFrame(index=freqvalues[0], data=freqvalues[1], columns=["Frequency"])
lotop.index.name = "Numbers"
lotop.sort_values(by=['Frequency'],ascending=False).head(10)
```